# How many ways are there to deal hands of $5$ cards to $6$ players?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is given as ${52 \choose 5}{47 \choose 5}{42 \choose 5}{37 \choose 5}{32 \choose 5}{27 \choose 5}$ because there are $52$ cards to choose from for the first person, $47$ to choose from for the second person, and so on.

But would we not have to multiply this by the number of ways in which we can order the players?

For example, the situation where player A gets dealt the first hand (which corresponds to $52\choose 5$) would be different than the situation where player B gets dealt the first hand.

For $6$ players we should have to multiply by $6!$ since there are $6!$ ways to order the players. Can someone explain why this logic incorrect, and under what different scenario (if any) would this logic be correct?

Comment: Player A still gets one of the ${52}\choose 5$ hands.

Comment: Do you consider being dealt first and being dealt second different?

Comment: Suppose that after shuffling but before dealing, the dealer reorders the cards in some way without knowing which card is which. Does this change which permutations of the deck are possible? Can there be any hand the players receive that they couldn't before reordering or vice versa?

Comment: Or are you really asking about the number of literal ways to deal hands of $5$ cards to $6$ players? As in the process of dealing a pile of cards, who gets the first card, who gets the second card, etc. all matters? That would be $\binom{30}5\binom{25}5\binom{20}5\binom{15}5\binom{10}5\binom{5}5 = \frac{30!}{\left(5!\right)^6}$.

Comment: Consider a much smaller problem where there are only two players and the deck only had two cards in it... the Ace of spades and the 2 of spades.  Let our players be named Frank and Steve.  What outcomes are there?  There should be sufficiently few that we can write them all out.  Frank gets the Ace and Steve gets the 2... Frank gets the 2 and Steve gets the Ace...  Only these, right?  What about Steve gets the 2 and Frank gets the Ace?  That was just the same as the first one I listed... at least so long as I don't care about "turn order" or where they are sitting or whatnot, just what cards

Comment: Compare this to a problem of asking how many ways I can give those two cards (*one each*) to Frank and Steve *and then give the "dealer chip"* to one of them in order to decide who goes first.  Okay, now we have four outcomes instead of just two.  With the way the original problem was written, we could just as well have assumed no such "dealer chip" (*or subsequent secondplayer chip, third player, etc...*) was handed out and that all we care about is who ends up with which cards and not caring in what order people received their cards.  Your answer is right for a different less common problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, that helps a lot. So essentially, the 6! term serves to count the number of ways in which the dealer chips that define turn order can be distributed, but since most games are not played with such dealer chips, the count without the 6! (or more generally, without the n! for an n-player game) is the most commonly applicable count.

Comment: @peterwhy Sorry, could you elaborate on the ${30 \choose 5}{25 \choose 5}{20 \choose 5}{15 \choose 5}{10 \choose 5}{5 \choose 5}$ count? I've now realized that if we consider being dealt first and being dealt second as different, then we need the 6! term, but if not then we drop the 6!. But I'm not sure where your chain of chooses starting at $30\choose 5$ is applicable.

Comment: What I was considering was a completely different problem from the ${52 \choose 5}{47 \choose 5}{42 \choose 5}{37 \choose 5}{32 \choose 5}{27 \choose 5}$ count. Consider there is a deck of at least $30$ cards, how many ways are there to deal the top of the deck to $6$ players until each player gets a hand of exactly $5$ cards? One way is to deal $5$ to the first, then $5$ to the next, ..., until the $6$th player. Another way is to deal one card each to each player in turn, starting from the $3$rd player. Or any order denoted by permutations of five $1$s, five $2$s, ..., and five $6$s.